# 'postgres_directory/tblspc' why no such directory is in my system

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, I installed Postgres-11 from source code, I was reading internals of PostgreSQL from this Website [Internals of postgresql](https://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql01.html).

I was learning table space part and the website is showing some directory named **tblspc** in the PostgreSQL.

I tried to find it in my system but there is no such directory.

Is this an issue or I can create it myself.

Comment: You mean `pg_tblspc` directory?

Comment: no it exists in demo (Database cluster directory)

Comment: So its empty and the book says that it has an oid for another tblspc right?

Comment: some thing like this but there is no such directory in my system may be I need to create it by myself right?

Comment: as per the book, pg_tblspc needs to have oid referring to another tblspc that is sort of logical link, however pg_tblspc is empty folder.

Comment: yes I know it is empty folder but tblspc in postgress installation folder in not in my system I'm asking about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation basically means that the tablespace folder should exist somewhere outside the database folder. This can be anywhere and the path is provided at the time of creation of tablespace.
This can be done using the following command after connecting to a database.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE tablespace_name
LOCATION 'absolute/path/to/tablespace/directory';
```

Make sure that the folder already exist. This will create a tablespace in the given folder with name `PG _ 'Major version' _ 'Catalogue version number'`.
To see the folder location of all the Tablespaces you can use this command.

```
select spcname
      ,pg_tablespace_location(oid) 
from   pg_tablespace;
```